# How to gain unlimited File System storage on web app

Tags: html, google-chrome, manifest, html5-filesystem

I would like to gain unlimited HTML 5 File System storage on my web page.

I though this could be realized by creating a manifest.json file:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "my-app",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "permissions": [
        "unlimitedStorage"
    ]
}
```

And referencing this file on my web page:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
```

However, I still get a `Quota Exceeded` error whenever I try to create a file:

```
window.webkitRequestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile('data.json', {
        create: true,
        exclusive: true
    },
..);
```

Since defining a manifest file was always mentioned in the context of creating a Chrome extension, I am not sure this actually works on a web page.

- So, is it possible to define a unlimitedStorage option for HTML 5
  File System on a web page?
- If not, what seems like the best alternative? *Just defining a huge
  size?*

**EDIT**

I am trying to get umlimited storage for my application. Currently, the needed storage `size` must be defined via the second parameter when calling `webkitRequestFileSystem`.

Comment: What do you mean by "unlimited file system storage"?  Are you trying to provide storage to users?  Are you trying to get storage for your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between [web application manifests](http://www.w3.org/TR/appmanifest/) and the [manifest.json](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest) files used by Chrome apps and extensions.

Web application manifests are referenced by a web page with the `<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">` html you used. They are a way to specify general information about an application, such as its name and icons.

Chrome apps and extensions also use manifest files, which follow a specific format used by the Chrome platform. Among the things you can define are permissions such as [unlimitedStorage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions), which allows the the app or extension to have an unlimited storage quota for certain HTML5 client-side data.

So you are correct that the unlimited storage permission is only available for Chrome apps or extensions, and you should just use a large number with `webkitRequestFileSystem`, such as 1024*1024*10 (10MB).

See [Managing HTML5 Offline Storage](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/offline_storage) for more information.